# Stripe Connect flow redirects to Login Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, stripes

I am trying to integrate Stripe Connect with Express accounts. However, I am having issues with Connect once I enter the `/oath/authorize` flow.

Initially, I navigate the user to the Connect flow as follows:

```
const url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize' +
              '?client_id=' + clientId +
              '&redirect_uri=' + location.origin +'/redirect' +
              '&stripe_user[email]=' + user.email +
              '&stripe_user[business_type]=individual' +
              '&state=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);

window.open(url,'_self');
```

As soon as the user enters the flow, values are pre-filled and gets prompted for a verification code.

[image]

[image]

Once the verification code is entered, Stripe redirects the user to a login page.

[image]

How can I prevent this from happening? Or what could I be doing wrong in the integration with Connect?

I also tried creating the link from the server using the `stripe.accountLinks.create` API function and sending the links to the front-end, but still, had the same issue.

Thank you!

Comment: "If [`redirect_uri`] provided, this must exactly match one of the comma-separated `redirect_uri` values in your application settings." Have you done this?

Comment: When going through the flow in test mode you need to open the OAuth link in an incognito window or a new browser to mimic the experience of a user first going through the OAuth flow. Otherwise, Stripe will see that you're "logged-in" and try to redirect you to the dashboard.

Comment: @ttmarek even in incognito window I am getting that Sign In page as part of the Connect  oauth flow. I don't understand what I am missing

Comment: @Daniel_Knights yes, I made sure that the uri is added in my settings

Comment: @chris, could you try with a unique email address? You can make any email address unique by adding a + and some characters after it. For example, jenny.rosen@example.com, becomes jenny.rosen+123456@example.com.

Comment: @ttmarek right, so I noticed emails that (most likely) have an account with stripe, are required to login in the flow. However, random-string emails just go through the flow. So I guess this is expected behavior

Comment: @chris, yeah, the basic idea is that if the email address already has a Stripe account, then they wouldn't have to create a new one.